# Eslint only working in one sublime text project?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint

I've duplicated a projects `.eslintrc` and `package.json` files, and only the first project gets linting.  The second project doesn't show any errors.

- I'm using sublime-linter, with the eslint mod.
- I've set the syntax the same in both projects.
- I've done an npm isntall
- I've tried restarting sublime
- on doing a comparison of the node_modules folders there is one descrepency, estravers-fb is installed in the project that works.

  - why would this not be installed in the other projects?
  - is there another command to properly install dev-dependancies other than npm isntall?

heres my package.json :

```
  {
    "name": "Read-hapi",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "learning the hapi framework",
    "repository": "https://github.com/Pushplaybang/learning-hapi.git",
    "main": "server.js",
    "dependencies": {
      "blipp": "^2.3.0",
      "boom": "^3.1.2",
      "cheerio": "^0.20.0",
      "good": "^6.6.0",
      "good-console": "^5.3.1",
      "handlebars": "^4.0.5",
      "hapi": "^13.0.0",
      "inert": "^3.2.0",
      "joi": "^8.0.3",
      "reading-time": "^1.0.2",
      "request-promise": "^2.0.1",
      "text-stats": "0.0.3",
      "valid-url": "^1.0.9",
      "vision": "^4.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
      "eslint": "^2.3.0",
      "eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.1.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "Paul van Zyl",
    "license": "ISC"
  }
```

and heres my .eslintrc

```
      {
        "parser": "babel-eslint",
        "extends": "airbnb",
        "env": {
          "browser": true,
          "node": true,
        },
        "rules": {
          "no-unused-vars": 0,
          "no-undef": 0,
        }
      }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading ESLint to `~2.2.0` in your package.json or using the default Espree parser instead of babel-eslint. There's an incompatibility right now between ESLint 2.3.0 and babel-eslint. We're tracking progress in [eslint/eslint#5476](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5476), and you can subscribe to that issue for updates.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, but I do ifind it strange that it works in one project and not another.

Comment: that did the trick downgrading to 2.2 was the winner! cheers.